# How to center div that contains an image within a div?

Tags: html, css

I need to center a image inside a div both vertically and horizontally. I am using the display inline-block property.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">
     <div class="image-container"><img src="image.gif"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to take out the image container div and put the image tag directly in the box. Then you can use vertical-align and text-align to center teh image

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of the image in advance?

Comment: @j08691 Yeah, I should've added that. It's 16x16px, if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach works perfectly for dynamic content of unknown dimensions.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HLnC9/)

Basically, we are using `vertical-align:middle` for vertical centering, and `text-align:center` for horizontal centering. In order for `vertical-align:middle` to work on a `div`, we need to set the parent elements to `display:table`, and the targeted child `div` to `display:table-cell`. Sure you could achieve such centering with `absolute` positoning, however, that would require you to know the dimensions of the `img`. This approach works for unknown dimensions.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
.container {
    display:table;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.box {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I was searching for this way, as i knew it did exist. +1

Comment: is this dynamic? Like when I shift the browser smaller will the table cells shift?

Answer (score 0):

for the horizantal you can use:

```
.box {
display: inline-block;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;  
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

for the vertical as far as i know you can use

```
#content {position:absolute; top:50%; height:240px; margin-top:-120px; /* negative half of the height */}
```

please read:
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image into a table like this:

```
  <table class="container">
     <tr class="box">
         <td class="image-container"><img src="image.gif"></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

And then use this in your CSS:

```
.image-container {
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x59tB/21/)

Comment: You might wanna test that.

Comment: It works and doesn't require absolute positioning. I added a JSFiddle. There may be a better way, but I haven't found one that works when absolute positioning won't, such as in a responsive design.