# Center both horizontally and vertically with variable size, maxing 1000px width/height;

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center vertically and horizontally an image with variable width and height, maxing at 1000px. I archived vertical center but I am unable to add horizontal center without breaking vertical... Here is my code:

```
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:70%;height:1000px;width:1000px;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;height:1000px;width:1000px;">
        <img src="images/a.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843811/how-to-center-div-that-contains-an-image-within-a-div/19844070#19844070

Comment: Great, but I need to do this without touching the body/html.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VSe2J/

Comment: Sadly is not, and if I change it, many things will not work correctly... :/

Comment: Show me an example and I will make it work. The height is just defined as there would otherwise not be a height, and thus, height:100% on the child would = 0px... Like I said, provide some sort of jsfiddle, and I will make it work without effecting the layout.

Comment: See my similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13356401/1057730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `text-align: center;` to outer `div`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVt9y/)